# ¿Cómo llamar a funciones definidas en otro archivo dentro de un Drive, con Google Colab?

Tags: python, funciones, google-colab

Trabajo con Google Colab, y tengo un archivo .ipynb con todas las funciones allí definidas. En otra carpeta del Drive tengo el código principal (otro archivo .ipynb), y quiero llamar a las funciones del otro archivo (sin tener que definirlas nuevamente en el código principal).

Estuve buscando soluciones pero ninguna me funcionó. Se agradecen los comentarios

Comment: Que has intentado??

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todos los Notebooks creados son guardados en nuestro Drive exactamente en una carpeta llamada `Colab Notebooks` y para acceder a otros archivos debemos de acceder a nuestro drive y buscar el archivo indicado en la carpeta mencionada anteriormente. La forma típica de importar otros Notebooks de Google Colab es usando el módulo `google` que nos ayuda a interactuar con los distintos servicios.

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Al ejecutar este código se te abrirá una ventana emergente en la cual tendrás que seleccionar la cuenta de Google donde tienes tus Notebooks, luego conceder todos los permisos y listo.

Ahora para importar los archivos debes de ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```py
%run "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/nombre_del_notebook.ipynb"
```

Y con eso ya tendrás tu archivo importado